# Consistency of the definition of total variation for functions of one or several variables

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Where can I find a proof that [the definition of total variation for functions of several variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_for_functions_of_n_%3E_1_real_variables) is consistent with [the definition of total variation for functions of one variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_for_functions_of_one_real_variable)?

Comment: This is addressed e.g. in the book *Functions of Bounded Variation* by L. Ambrosio, N. Fusco and D. Pallara (2000). See e.g. section 3.2 therein.

Comment: @Skeeve I couldn't find it. What proposition is it?

Comment: you are right, in that book it is stated just one way in Theorem 3.28 (see the discussion of good representatives). But if you want an explicit statement about equivalence of the two definitions then have a look at Theorem 1 in section 5.10.1 of *Measure theory and fine properties of functions* by L.C. Evans and R.F. Gariepy (1992).

Comment: @Skeeve Found it. That's great. Thank you.